# Using semicolon in REST endpoint (not for separating query parameters)

Tags: api, rest, api-design

Lets say you have REST endpoint `/articles`. To get an article, the end point will `articles/:id`. Now say, you have to find articles with search filter, I saw a URI of the form `/articles;find` (filter in POST body). I felt it should it be `/articles/find` and known problem with former approach is majority of libraries are not going to parse the URI correctly . I look at popular REST APIs and I do not see the semicolon approach anywhere. Yet, I am not sure as what is the correct approach for defining the find article REST endpoint.

Answer (score 3):

HTTP provides a way for doing filters, which can act as searches, using query strings. So you wouldn't have a resource called "find", you would use a query string on the resource collection that you wish to search, in this case the `articles` resource. For example `/articles?category=biology`. This resource should return links to articles that match the query string. If you leave out the query string it should return links to all articles.